# Android- Thread.join() causes Application to hang

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a thread which handles my game loop, when i call .join() on this thread the application stops responding. 
I've been trying to fix a problem where the programs never get to the code, I.E the thread never ends.

```
System.out.println("YAY");
```

My Thread for the Game Loop:

This thread successfully prints out "Game Ended" but never seems to finish.

```
Runnable startGameLoop = new Runnable() {//game loop
          @Override
          public void run() {

              AiFactory ai = new AiFactory();
              final Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Play);
              final Button pass = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Pass);

              while(finish==false){
                  try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                  currentPlayer = game.getPlayer();

                  if(currentPlayer.isPlayer()==false){

                      //System.out.println("passCount:" +game.getPasscount());
                      ai.decide(nextPlay, game.getPreviousPlayed(), currentPlayer, game.getPasscount() );
                      if(nextPlay.size()!=0){
                          runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                            public void run(){
                                changeArrow();
                                if(nextPlay.size() ==1){
                                    play1Card();
                                }
                                else if(nextPlay.size()==2){
                                    play2Card();
                                }
                                else if(nextPlay.size()==3){
                                    play3Card();
                                }
                                else if(nextPlay.size()==5){
                                    play5Card();
                                }
                            }
                      }
                      else{
                          game.addPassCount();
                          game.nextTurn();
                          runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                                public void run(){
                                    changeArrow();
                                }
                            });
                      }     
                   }
                   else if (currentPlayer.isPlayer()==true){
                      runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                            public void run(){
                                changeArrow();
                                play.setClickable(true);
                                 if(game.getPasscount()==3){
                                     pass.setClickable(false);
                                 }
                                 else{
                                     pass.setClickable(true);
                                 }
                            }
                        });
                  }

             }
             System.out.println("Game Ended");
          }
     };
```

Starting and joining the thread to the main thread:

```
     Thread myThread = new Thread(startGameLoop);

     myThread.start();
     try {
        myThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     System.out.println("YAY");
}
```

To my understanding .join() makes the current thread wait till the new thread has finished before carrying on.

Sorry if this is a stupid question, i'm quite new to threading.

Comment: We need a little more context. Where does this call to `join()` occur. Most likely you are doing this on the UI thread which would explain why your app hangs.

Comment: join occurs in onCreate() in a Activity Class

Comment: So your app is waiting for a thread to terminate before it finishes creating the Activity. Is this *really* what you want to do? If not, what *are* you trying to do here?

Comment: Ah, this was 2 part error on my part. I inserted interrupts to end my thread and it was also because i was blocking the UI thread with the join call.
Thanks for the heads up guys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `myThread.join()` inside `Activity.onCreate` you block the main UI thread. Of course it looks like your application has stopped responding because the UI thread is the one responsible for redrawing UI. All your calls `runOnUiThread` never happen because your UI thread is busy waiting on your game loop.

Answer (score 7):

Thread.join makes the current thread wait until the thread you call it on ends.  It does not cause the thread you call it on to end.  So if that thread is never ending (as you say at the top), calling join will make it hang forever.

If you want to actually end the thread, call cancel on it.  But that requires your thread to occasionally call isCanceled() and exit its run function if it returns true.

Answer (score 1):

mythread.join() does not ensure that your "mythread" is ended.

You need to place a notify() in your game loop.

...
...

```
System.out.println("Game Ended");
synchronized(mythread){
    mythread.notify();
}
```

Basically, when you make a call to wait(), the code waits on the thread's monitor, and a call to notify() causes a thread waiting on the object's monitor to wake up.
Also, you can use notifyAll() to wake up all the waiting threads.

Alternatively, you can use timeout version of wait(), where the thread waits either till it gets notified or it times out.

Comment: You'd better use `Lock` with `Condition` to better achieve this