# Should I call thread.join in onDestroy()

Tags: android, multithreading

Is it good to call `Thread.join` in onDestroy? Or just tell the thread to stop and leave it?

For example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private Thread myThread;
    private volatile boolean running = true;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while(running) {
                    // Do something
                }
            }
        });
        myThread.start();
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        running = false;
        try {
            myThread.join(); // Is it good to calling it here? Or just let it fininsh itself?
        } catch(InterruptedException e){}
    }
}
```

I know calling `join()` might block the UI thread, but what would happen if the activity finishes before the thread without calling `join()`?
What does the system do to the threads after the activity is destroyed? Does it wait for them, put them in background, or kill them?

Comment: Not related but make `running` as `atomic` or `volatile`. Read about threads visibility

Comment: @EugenMartynov Thanks for reminder. I almost forget there's a `volatile` in java.

Comment: IMO not point in calling, in fact it seems like a bad idea - blocking the main `Thread` when Android desperately needs resources( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962646/android-thread-join-causes-application-to-hang)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, don't.  Thread.join() doesn't destroy a Thread-  it waits for it to finish.  This could take a very long time (or forever).  It should only be called if doing so won't make the app unresponsive (if its not on the UI thread) and if you absolutely cannot continue without that thread being finished.  Neither one is true here.

Comment: So should I just set the `running` flag and leave the thread even if it might be running forever?

Comment: THe purpose of the running flag here is to force the Thread to stop running at the top of the loop, right?  So yes, just set it and move on.  If it works, it works.  If it doesn't, all thread.join would do is make your app freeze.  it wouldn't actually force the thread to stop.

Comment: Is there any way to know if it doesn't work and is running forever if I don't have `join()`?

Comment: Unless your thread is blocking forever on IO or something its going to work.  I'd really just check for that as a bench test-  if 30 seconds or so later the thread is still running in your debugger and hasn't been finished, it didn't work.